# Sum of flow network functions

Tags: functions, graph-theory, network-flow

It might be a pretty silly question but..

What is the sum of two flow network functions? 
You just go and make the sum of each flow function for every edge?

Let
f1 and f2 two flow functions
a graph G=(V, E) 
e1, e2 are edges from E

f1(e1) = 5, f1(e2) = 3 
f2(e1) = 2, f2(e2) = 3

If f = f1 + f2, then f(e1) = 7 and f(e2) = 6? Or I'm getting something wrong?

Comment: Hint: The flow functions form a vector space.

Comment: It says that the sum is in the same form. So I was right?